# Install custom theme on google devtools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to install a custom theme on google devtools.
I am following this guide
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/chrome-devtools-theme/
I am copying and pasting the theme on custom.css but it doesn't change the devtools at all.

Answer (score 1):

That method of styling DevTools was an accident. Never actually intended to work. The bug that allowed it was patched.

There is a theme API for extensions if you want to build one of those. It is hidden under a DevTools Experiments flag.

However, a default Dark theme is making its way down the road (already in Dev channel.) I would wager custom themes API could get removed once that has been out for a bit, but nothing is solid (or even talked about to this extent.)

#### tl;dr

Theming DevTools with a custom theme is a painful process and not recommended.